# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLocalpath（Configuration）

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Does anyone have this problem before?

```
The following are the error information when I run the job:
13/01/10 15:53:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201301101540_0001_m_000010_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLocalPath(Configuration.java:934)
    at nfs.iscas.sil.hcir.index.ImageIndexWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at nfs.iscas.sil.hcir.index.ImageIndexOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your path.

`file file-path of resource to be added, the local filesystem is examined directly to find the resource, without referring to the classpath.`